# How to load a symbol library in Illustrator using javascript?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

By code, I'm trying to load a symbol library from a reference Illustrator file to another.
I would like to do the same load as when you click on 'Other Library' in the UI then you have to choose an Ai file to get all its symbols.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do it? Is there an easy way or should I copy the symbols one after the other?

I have tried to load the other document then copy each symbol to the first document:

```
var loadSymbolLibrary = function(fromAiFile) {
    var thisDocument = activeDocument;
    app.open(fromAiFile);
    var fromAiDocument = activeDocument;

    var symbols = fromAiDocument.symbols;
    for(var i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
        var symbol = symbols[i];
        thisDocument.symbols.add(symbol);
    }

    fromAiDocument.close();
    activeDocument = thisDocument;
}
```

But I get an error when adding a symbol to the first document.
According to the Adobe documentation, I need a `PageItem` and a `SymbolRegistrationPoint` to create a symbol with the `add()` function.

[EDIT]

I also tried to load the document containing symbols in this way:

```
    var openOptions = new OpenOptions();
openOptions.openAs = LibraryType.SYMBOLS;
var symbolDocument = app.open(symbolAiFile, null, openOptions);
```

This opens a symbol window in Illustrator, but I don't know how to deal with it by code as calling `symbolDocument.symbols` produce a 'The document is no longer open' error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it will be useful to know for clarity that a *SymbolItem* is a placed instance of a *Symbol* and a *Document* has both of those.

Illustrator will not allow a call to `Document.symbolItems.add()` if the symbol being passed is not in that document's symbols list. Personally, I consider that a bug. Here is a wrapper class that opens the symbol library as a new document (note the exclusion of relevant openAs property), places the symbol into that document, then copies the symbol item to the other document.

```
#target illustrator-18


//class
function SymbolLibrary(){

    this.symbolsDoc = null;
    this.len = 0;

    this.begin = function(symbolFileName){
        var file1 = File(symbolFileName);
        //open the symbol library
        var optRef = new OpenOptions();
        //optRef.openAs = LibraryType.SYMBOLS; //broken. just open as regular doc
        this.symbolsDoc = app.open( file1 , null , optRef);
        this.len = this.symbolsDoc.symbols.length;
        return this.symbolsDoc;
    }

    this.list = function(){
        for(var i=0;i<symbolsDoc.symbols.length;i++){
            $.writeln( symbolsDoc.symbols[i] );
        }
        return symbolsDoc.symbols;
    }

    this.place = function(targetDoc,index){
        var symbolItem = this.symbolsDoc.symbolItems.add(this.symbolsDoc.symbols[index]);
        finalItem = symbolItem.duplicate( targetDoc,ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND );
        symbolItem.remove();
        return finalItem;
    }

    this.end = function(){
    this.symbolsDoc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    }
}

var filename =  "/Applications/Adobe\ Illustrator\ CC\ 2014/"+
    "Presets.localized/en_US/Symbols/Nature.ai";


//create new document
var mydoc = app.documents.addDocument('',new DocumentPreset());

//instantiate the symbol library handler class
var lib1 = new SymbolLibrary();

lib1.begin(filename);
for(var i=0;i<lib1.len;i++){
    lib1.place(mydoc,i).position = [((i%10)*100),i*10];
}
lib1.end();

$.writeln('#########');
```